# Sysprep changing default language

Tags: windows-10, sysprep, language-pack, answerfile

I have a Windows 10 Enterprise system with these installed languages:

English (United Kingdom) & Japanese (Japan)

Now I run Sysprep on the machine, and for some reason, English (United States) is added and set as the default language.

How can I avoid this? My answer file has no mention of en-US... Could it be picking it up from somewhere else?

```
<settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <InputLocale>en-GB;ja-JP</InputLocale>
        <SystemLocale>en-GB</SystemLocale>
        <UILanguage>en-GB</UILanguage>
        <UILanguageFallback>en-GB</UILanguageFallback>
        <UserLocale>en-GB</UserLocale>
    </component>
```

**Edit**

Further detail I didn't consider - Before running sysprep, English (Ireland) is also installed and is the default language and after the sysprep it's gone. This is OK for my purposes (however I though it worth mentioning in case it helps).

Comment: What language was the ISO used to install Windows?

Comment: @Ramhound - actually I'm not sure as I don't have it to hand now... I can check in a few days, but I have resolved the problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I set English (United Kingdom) to default and removed English (Ireland). This seems to have fixed it, now the Sysprep doesn't introduce English (United States) and correctly leaves en-GB as the default language.

It seems to have been confused by en-IE or something...